# Increasing Letterspace for words in caps or small caps

Tags: spacing, small-caps, microtype

Some typographers say it's a good habit to increase the letterspace when writing words in caps or small caps. So my question is, how to do it with pdflatex and/or xelatex? And while we're at it, which words would you alter this way? Acronyms like USA, NATO, IBM, GNU, etc.? How about words like PCs, UdSSR, FreeBSD or TV-Station?

Answer (score 21):

Use the microtype package, loading it with `[tracking=smallcaps]` should take care of small caps

For all-uppercase words you can use microtype's `\textls`, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\versal}[1]{\textscale{0.9}{\textls*[80]{#1}}}
```

(I came across this [here](http://www.zvisionwelt.de/?page_id=56), check the provided “Präambel”, the spacing/scaling might be font specific, so use with care and check your output, maybe someone else could comment on this one)

hope this helps

Answer (score 15):

In XeLaTeX with the fontspec package you can select a font with the LetterSpace feature:

```
\newcommand\tracked[1]{%
  {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2}#1}}
```

LetterSpace=s is an additional s/F space between letters where F is the font size.

(I swear I once saw an example of letterspacing involving additional glue rather than just fixed space, but I can't see anything around that this could be. Any idea?)

Answer (score 4):

Another example, this is what's used in the TUGboat journal:

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\def\acro#1{\textsmaller{#1}\@}
```

They also have a list of abbreviations/acronyms you can use to get some ideas how/what to letterspace, see
[tugboat.dtx](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tugboat/tugboat.dtx)

For example,

```
\def\MacOSX{Mac\,\acro{OS\,X}}
```

or

```
\def\MathML{Math\acro{ML}}
```

You can use the microtype package and AssBurger's `\versal` command if you want additional microtypgraphic features like increased letterspace.

Answer (score 4):

Something I found on a [UK mailing list](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterspace) while searching for a solution to increase the letterspace that I think is important to know:

> Possibly the ‘ultimate’ in this field is the **microtype**, which uses the
> micro-typography capabilities of current PDFTeX to provide a \textls
> command, which operates according to parameters declared in a
> \SetTracking command. Microtype’s ‘tracking’ facility **expands the
> natural spacing font itself, rather than inserting space between
> characters**.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! `microtype` and its `\textls` command were already pointed out in Assburger's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the nice welcome!
With my answer I just wanted to highlight, that `\textls` _builds on the natural spacing of the font_. If I have to decide among a selection of working solutions, I would choose this one because of consistency.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use the [soul](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) package for letterspacing with xelatex since microtype is not supported yet by xelatex (as far as I know)

I would use letterspacing on small caps for titles.

Comment: As long as you don't use non-ascii characters, it seems. All č, ć, ž, đ, š letters are simply lost with soul.

Comment: @MehoR.Use Heiko Oberdiek’s extended package `soulutf8`: see the documentation at http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/soulutf8.pdf